# Importing React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module

I have php page and import React as s file

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="/assets/app.js"></script>
```

in app.js file

```
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<MyApp/>);
```

app.js use jsx so I render it by console command

*npx babel ./views/post/app.js -d --out-file ./web/assets/app.js --plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx*

everything works but app.js became bigger. because I write many components, so I decide devcide it on modules
I made SeoKeywords.js file

```
export default function SeoKeywords() {
    return (......)
}
```

And now I try to import it as it say here https://react.dev/learn/importing-and-exporting-components

I added *import SeoKeywords from './SeoKeywords'; in top of app.js*
now in asset folder I have **app.js** ad **SeoKeywords.js**

when page is load I have error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at app.js:1:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the import syntax in a script, you need to specify its type as a module, i.e:

```
<script type="module" src="/assets/app.js"></script>
```

MDN's page has a great introduction on what modules are and how they work, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#a_background_on_modules